# Is it possible to save results of a Hypertable shell query into a file?

Tags: hypertable

I need some data out of my hypertable. I can inspect the data with the hypertable shell and was curios whether it is possible to pipe the result of a HQL query into a file. This would be useful for further investigations when the result set is large and one wants to format it or something else.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure:

```
SELECT * FROM table INTO FILE "file.txt";
```

You can even compress the file:

```
SELECT * FROM table INTO FILE "file.txt.gz";
```

Type `help select` in the shell and you will get more info.

Comment: worked fine, it seems that i miss this in the description. thanks!

Comment: You can also use 'ht shell --config config_file --namespace xyz < query.hql > /tmp/store_in_this_file.dat' to accomplish the same thing. query.hql will have your SELECT statement.